# Slicing filtered DataFrame or Series (slicing observed results with negative index)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, slice

There is a simple DataFrame and I would like to get some last results - I tried to use the negative indexing for this, but faced with an empty result.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', freq = '3D', periods=8)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

print(df)
print(df.D.iloc[-1])
print(df.D.iloc[-2])
print(df.D.iloc[-1:-2])
```

Out:

```
2000-01-01 -1.174492 -1.186283 -0.514886  1.260030
2000-01-04 -0.795413 -0.389328  0.953518  1.130829
2000-01-07  0.735389  0.797403  0.240489  2.901620
2000-01-10 -0.387048  0.412311 -0.386004  0.477054
2000-01-13 -0.470163  0.519287 -0.422162 -0.383079
2000-01-16  0.249516  1.338018 -1.531770  0.816327
2000-01-19  0.367816 -0.021173  1.553473  0.267708
2000-01-22 -0.742793  1.028269 -0.306251  0.792746
0.7927456864860766
0.26770835612718263
Series([], Freq: 3D, Name: D, dtype: float64)
```

As you can see, negative indexing works fine to get scalar values themselves, but it doesn't work to slice the Series of df - e.g. I just want to get 2 last values.

How can I do it using indexing or function?

Comment: I found it's possible to do via tail() function `print(df.D.tail(2))` but still I don't understand why it's not possible to use negative indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to do if you want to do negative indexing for last two number:

```
df.D.iloc[-2:]
```

if you do `df.D.iloc[-1:-2]`, it implies that you are trying to start from last index and end at second index (end is not inclusive); but **without specifying step it won't work.**

for example, you can do instead:

```
df.D.iloc[-1:-3:-1] # to get last two value but reversed
```

Comment: it works but changes the order of values from the DataFrame to the opposite (reversed), as you mentioned. Thank you for your solution `df.D.iloc[-2:] ` It's strange I couldn't find it in pandas documentation of Indexing section. If you have a link щт Pandas doc about negative indexing, please share it with me

Comment: pandas indexing works just the same as python list indexing

Answer (score 0):

I made a stupid mistake - I tried to slice using `-1` as the beginning of the slicing and `-2` as its end :) which was a brutal mistake `df.D.iloc[-1:-2]`.

So, if we just use **`df.D.iloc[-2:-1] or [-2:]`**, everything will work perfectly. Thank you @ABC for your help